# Can you append values to a GraphQL query?

Tags: typescript, oracle, graphql, typeorm

I am using GraphQL and Typeorm with an Oracle Db and I am trying to select all data within a particular table. The query executing is

`SELECT "inventory"."id" AS "inventory_id", "inventory"."value" AS "inventory_value", "inventory"."description" AS "inventory_description" FROM "inventory" "inventory"`

When it should be

`SELECT "inventory"."id" AS "inventory_id", "inventory"."value" AS "inventory_value", "inventory"."description" AS "inventory_description" FROM "dbname.inventory"`

The database "dbname", is through a Public Oracle Database Link.

Is there anyway for me to append "dbname." to the table portion of the GraphQL query or is there a better way to make the fix?

Attached is my model and resolver and please let me know if you have any questions/suggestions. Thanks in advance and let me know if there is anything that needs clarified.

```
// Inventory.ts
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BaseEntity } from "typeorm";
import { ObjectType, Field } from "type-graphql";

@Entity()
@ObjectType()
export class inventory extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid") id: number;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  value: number;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  description: string;
  
}
```

```
// InventoryResolver.ts
import { Resolver, Query } from "type-graphql";
import { inventory } from "../../models/Inventory";

@Resolver(inventory)
export class InventoryResolver {
  constructor() {}

  @Query(() => inventory, { nullable: true })
  async queryInventory() {
    return inventory.find();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to to the `type-graphql` resolver. You just have to specify database name in the configuration of `@Entity` decorator. So according to [typeorm decorator reference](https://typeorm.io/#/decorator-reference/entity):

```
...
@Entity({
  name: "inventory"
  database: "dbname", // <-- 
})
@ObjectType()
export class inventory extends BaseEntity {
...
```

Comment: I added your suggest and can see changes when using the decorator. When trying to query I'm getting an error on the query and table does not exist. Are my issues occurring because I need to pull through a DB link for `dbname.inventory`?